# Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error. [ExecutablePath /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd

Tags: sound

I was having a problem with my ubuntu vm where the sound was not being heard from it.
After clicking on settings on the workstation vm and selecting
"Specify host sound card:" and then manually pointing to the pc sound card sound works well!

But after logging in I keep getting this annoying error
Any help is appreciated!

[image]

[image]

===========
Here is the output of

```
$ ls -alt /var/crash
total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Aug 22 23:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Apr 10 23:52 ..
```

Comment: In `terminal` show me `ls -alt /var/crash`.

Comment: Hi Here is the output
total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Aug 22 23:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Apr 10 23:52 ..

Comment: The output of the `ls` command needs to be copy/pasted into your original question, because in the comments, it is hard to read, and it cuts off the information. Please do this again for me. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have this info.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for the tip...I have added the info that you have requested...Thanks for all your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

`/var/crash` didn't give me any clues as to the nature of your problem.

If you keep seeing the same crash report time after time, it's probably because you're clicking on the X (close) instead of clicking on the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button.

Sending an error report is optional, so you can uncheck the "Send error report" if you choose.